How to get all picked entities in Qt3D when entities overlap?
I am developping an app relying on Qt3D and using PySide2.
I've several entities in my scene, some of them overlapping. Each of my entities have a QObjectPicker component and the QPickingSettings result mode of the scene is set to AllPicks.
The goal is to select (i.e. change color) of entities when they are clicked. If only one entity is on the mouse ray then just this entity is selected. If several entities are overlapping behind the mouse ray then I'd like to retrieve their IDs and ask the user which one he wants to select.
The problem is that I did not manage to get more than one entity react to click. If I've two spheres, perfectly one behind the other, only one of them will fire it's clicked signal when picking.
Here is a sample code,the print exhibit that the setSelected method of NodeEntity is called only for one instance of NodeEntity. I guess that I could get all entities by accessing the PickResult However I did not manage to intercept it.
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PySide2.Qt3DCore import Qt3DCore
from PySide2.Qt3DExtras import Qt3DExtras
from PySide2.Qt3DRender import Qt3DRender


       
class NodeEntity(Qt3DCore.QEntity):
    def __init__(self,rootEntity,x,y,z,index):
        super().__init__(rootEntity)
        
        self.index=index
        
        self.Geo=Qt3DExtras.QSphereMesh()
        self.Geo.setRadius(0.5)
        self.Transform = Qt3DCore.QTransform()
        self.Transform.setTranslation(QtGui.QVector3D(x,y,z))

        self.Material = Qt3DExtras.QDiffuseSpecularMaterial(
            diffuse=QtGui.QColor('green'),
            ambient=QtGui.QColor('green'),
            specular=QtGui.QColor('green')
        )
        
        self.addComponent(self.Geo)
        self.addComponent(self.Transform)
        self.addComponent(self.Material)
        
        
        self.selected=False
        self.picker=Qt3DRender.QObjectPicker(self)
        # self.picker.setHoverEnabled(True)
        self.addComponent(self.picker)
        # self.picker.entered.connect(self.setRed)
        # self.picker.exited.connect(self.setColor)
        self.picker.clicked.connect(self.setSelected)
        self.picker.setEnabled(True)
        
            
    def setSelected(self,event):
        print(self.index)
        if not self.selected:
            self.selected=True
            self.Material.setDiffuse(QtGui.QColor('violet'))
            self.Material.setAmbient(QtGui.QColor('violet'))
            self.Material.setSpecular(QtGui.QColor('violet'))
        elif self.selected:
            self.selected=False
            self.Material.setDiffuse(QtGui.QColor('green'))
            self.Material.setAmbient(QtGui.QColor('green'))
            self.Material.setSpecular(QtGui.QColor('green'))

            

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        
        self.view = Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow(None,Qt3DRender.API.OpenGL)
        self.view.defaultFrameGraph().setClearColor(QtGui.QColor(225,235,255))
        self.view.renderSettings().pickingSettings().setPickResultMode(Qt3DRender.QPickingSettings.AllPicks)
        self.view.renderSettings().setRenderPolicy(Qt3DRender.QRenderSettings.OnDemand)
        
        container = self.createWindowContainer(self.view)
        screenSize = self.view.screen().size()
        container.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 100))
        container.setMaximumSize(screenSize)
        
        self.rootEntity = Qt3DCore.QEntity()
        
        self.cameraEntity = self.view.camera()
        self.cameraEntity.lens().setProjectionType(Qt3DRender.QCameraLens.PerspectiveProjection)
        self.cameraEntity.lens().setFieldOfView(60)
        self.cameraEntity.lens().setAspectRatio(16/9)
        
        self.cameraEntity.lens().setFarPlane(1000)
        self.cameraEntity.lens().setNearPlane(0.1)
        
        self.cameraEntity.setPosition(QtGui.QVector3D(0, 0, 5))
        self.cameraEntity.setUpVector(QtGui.QVector3D(0, 1, 0))
        self.cameraEntity.setViewCenter(QtGui.QVector3D(0, 0, 0))

        lightEntity = Qt3DCore.QEntity(self.rootEntity)
        light = Qt3DRender.QPointLight(lightEntity)
        light.setColor("white")
        light.setIntensity(1)
        lightEntity.addComponent(light)

        lightTransform = Qt3DCore.QTransform(lightEntity)
        lightTransform.setTranslation(self.cameraEntity.position())
        lightEntity.addComponent(lightTransform)

        self.camController = Qt3DExtras.QOrbitCameraController(self.rootEntity)
        self.camController.setCamera(self.cameraEntity)
        self.camController.setEnabled(True)
        
        self.view.setRootEntity(self.rootEntity)
        
        
        self.mainLayout=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(container)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        
        self.node1=NodeEntity(self.rootEntity, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        self.node2=NodeEntity(self.rootEntity, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        
                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = Window(parent=app.desktop())
    widget.setWindowTitle("Basic shapes")
    widget.show()
    widget.resize(1200, 800)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Have you tried setting the rendering mode to 'Always'? And which Qt3D version are you using? I remember that there were a lot of bugs on old Qt3D versions, maybe it works when you always render.

Thanks for your answer, I'm working with PySide2 5.15.2. The same occur with Always rendering mode.
